# Перебор массива каждые 3 элемента

Tags: javascript

Приветствую!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно перебирать массив каждые 3 элемента. У меня есть массив `var arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]` Мне нужно через for вывести так:

```
Первый: 1, 2, 3.
Второй: 4, 5, 6.
Третий: 7, 8, 9.
```

Я сделал все через такой перебор:

```
for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     for( var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
         console.log(arr[i][j]);
     }
 }
```

и так три раза, увеличивая i и j на 3. Как это можно автоматизировать, что бы не 3 раза выводить for.
Большое всем спасибо за ответы! 
А если у меня есть такой массив:

```
arr = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]
```

И мне необходимо найти первые три индекса каждого значения, что бы получилось так:
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6] и тд.
Как это можно сделать? 
Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: У вас всегда это массив в массиве? А внутренних массивов может быть несколько?

Comment: @ThisMan, на оба вопроса ответ - да

Comment: @Aleksander Значит мой ответ не полный, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Данные всегда в массиве второго уровня? Глубже не будет?

Comment: Нет, только второго уровня

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот как можно это сделать:

```js
var arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [12, 3, 4, 11, 4, 5, 6, 7]];
    var tmp_arr = [];
    var arr_3 = [];
    for(var j=0; j<arr.length;j++){
        arr_3[j] = [];
        for( var i = 0; i < arr[j].length; i=i+3){
            tmp_arr = [];
            tmp_arr.push(arr[j][i]);
            if(typeof arr[j][i+1] != 'undefined'){
                tmp_arr.push(arr[j][i+1]);
            }
            if(typeof arr[j][i+2] != 'undefined'){
                tmp_arr.push(arr[j][i+2]);
            }
            arr_3[j].push(tmp_arr);
        }
    }
    console.log(arr_3);
```

Вот второй вариант после вашего обновления вопроса:

```js
let arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [12, 3, 4, 11, 4, 5, 6, 7]];

let subarr_count = 3;


function new_arr(arr, subarr_count){
    let tmp_arr = [];
    let arr_3 = [];
    for(var j=0; j<arr.length;j++){

        let ar_count = Math.floor(arr[j].length/subarr_count);

        arr_3[j] = [];

        tmp_arr = [];

        tmp_arr.push(arr[j][0]);

        if(typeof arr[j][1] != 'undefined'){
            tmp_arr.push(arr[j][1]);
        }
        if(typeof arr[j][2] != 'undefined'){
            tmp_arr.push(arr[j][2]);
        }
        for(var i=0; i<ar_count; i++){
            arr_3[j].push(tmp_arr);
        }
    }
    return arr_3;
}
console.log(new_arr(arr, subarr_count));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понял, внутренних массивов может быть сколько угодно, поэтому я немного усложнил входной массив.

```js
var arr1 = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, [8, [9, 10]]],
  [11, 12, [13, [14,15]]]
];

function getArray(arr, num) {
  var result = [];
  var i = 0;
  var calculateArr = function(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
      if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        calculateArr(item);
      } else {
        let reminder = Math.floor(i / num);
        if (!result[reminder]) {
          result[reminder] = [];
        }
        result[reminder].push(item);
        i++;
      }
    });
  }
  calculateArr(arr);

  return result;
}

console.log('arr1  = ' + JSON.stringify(getArray(arr1, 3)));

var arr2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

console.log('arr2 = ' + JSON.stringify(getArray(arr2, 3)));
```

После обновления вопроса решение приняло следующий вид:

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
];

function getNewArr(arr) {
  let result = [];
  arr.forEach(function(innerArr) {
    innerArr.forEach(function(item, i) {
      let reminder = Math.floor(i / 3);
      if (!result[reminder]) {
        result[reminder] = [];
      }
      result[reminder].push(item);
    });
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getNewArr(arr)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так будет работать на разное кол-во

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

function breakUp(array){
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 3) {
    console.log(array.slice(i, i + 3));
  }
}

breakUp(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если просто вывести данные.

```js
  var arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],
    length = 3,
    test = document.getElementById('test');
    
  function display() {
    arr.forEach(item => {
      for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
          test.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ( !i || i % length ? " ": "<br/>") + item[i])
      }
      test.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<br/>")
    })
  }
  
  
  display();
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Что-то у вас [пошло не так](https://www.screencast.com/t/U7CPTaJlV)...

Comment: @AGS17 точно, спасибо.  Не заметил что i вывожу вместо массива